# How can I convert obsolete word processor files and preserve formatting?

Tags: software, file-conversion, word-processor

I have some files in WriteNow and WordPerfect format. The WriteNow files go back as far as 1987 and the WordPerfect files are from 1998 - 2001. Some I can read, others I can't open at all. Those I can read lose most of the formatting.

I'm talking basic "RTF-like" formatting for the most part, not super obscure proprietary word processing features à la the Home Depot that is MS Word. There are also some embedded graphics in whatever was the generic standard for Macintosh back then.

Even if a file might be in RTF, that standard has changed significantly over the years and formatting is lost for the most part.

I don't have the original software or a machine to run it on.

Comment: RTF does not have a standard :(

Comment: Well, yes and no. [There are several different revisions of RTF specification and portability of files will depend on what version of RTF is being used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

Comment: ah I used it on NeXT and I think before " Microsoft did not initially make the RTF specification publicly available"

Comment: I have just read that link to Wikipedia and it shows Wikis limits - The MacOs Textedit is an update NeXt app and needs the history shown back to 1989 and also differs from other MacApps I suspect.

Answer (score 5):

for WordPerfect documents, you can also try to use OpenOffice, LibreOffice, NeoOffice (...), libwpd filter (see http://libwpd.sourceforge.net/features.html ) will then be used to convert the document in odt format.

For WriteNow files, the best solution is probably using an emulator. If you have access to a 64 bit Intel Mac with OsX 10.6 ( or 10.7), you can also find on http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmwaw/files/ a precompilated version of a WriteNow filter to odt : mwawOSX.zip ; ie I tried to write a small filter to convert WriteNow files, it works "well enough" on the few WriteNow files that I had found, so maybe it can work also for your files ( or maybe not :-~ ).

Comment: LibreOffice worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

NeoOffice seems to be able to open all my old files, WordPerfect and WriteNow!

Comment: Maybe you could expand on this answer a bit? Include a link to NeoOffice and some screen shots of some converted files if possible? It's a nice answer now, but with some effort it could be a really excellent answer.

Comment: I used this answer successfully. I used LibreOffice (of which NeoOffice is a fork) to open an old WriteNow! document. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you can find someone in your local Mac users group who has a working copy of DataViz's discontinued MacLink Plus product, you may be able to convert the files to a modern format.

If you have access to a Classic-capable machine (10.4 PPC), you could try the freeware version of FullWrite Pro from this site http://www.encyclomedia.ca/fwp/

Comment: I don't believe MacLink Plus will run under Lion.

Comment: jaberg, of course you are right. What you really need is a working Mac running Mac OS 8 or Mac OS 9 and the DataViz MacLink product. Good luck.

Comment: I have maclink plus deluxe running on Snow Leopard. I can see text but formatting is not there and the graphics are missing

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to find old hardware; much of what is described above can be done in an emulator like Basilisk II and, depending on your attitude towards pirating ancient software, you can probably find the old applications online as well (see for example http://www.macintoshgarden.org/apps/word-processing-presentation).  I salvaged work in Pagemaker 2 format (circa 1991) with an emulator recently.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed LibreOffice on Mac and it reads Writenow files without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I can't address the specific file formats you're dealing with, but I had to do a manual conversion of some older AppleWorks documents. (AppleWorks v. 5 — Pages won't open them.)

This is a *last ditch* effort, something to try once other methods have failed.

I was able to open them as plain text files in TextEdit by selecting the documents in the finder and using *Open With…* from the contextual menu. Each document had a *noisy* header and footer, which I deleted, but the body of the work was present.

Then I read through and removed *junk* (extraneous) characters and re-formatted the document using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). If there had been more documents, or had they been longer, I would have brought the text file over to BBEdit, and used a series of *search/replace* to clean up the documents.